# Use GOPATH in golang makefile or init go mod first?

Tags: go, makefile, go-modules, gopath

I'm learning to write Golang makefile and got some confused me because some examples they config GO env such as `GOOS, GOPATH, GOBASE` before building. But normally I can use `go mod init` to create go module and in Makefile use `go build`  to build my project.
So what's is the best approach ?

Comment: If you have a choice - use `go mod`. GOPATH builds are considered legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Modern `go` code with `go mod`. `Makefile` should not include `GOPATH`. Just use `go build` is enough.

see https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Comment: In Makefile, using `go build` without `go mod init projectName` ahead gives me an error: `go: cannot find main module` But If I include `go mod init ProjectName` and `go mod tidy`, I cannot `make build` multiple times because the following build will try to do `go mod init` again, which is not allowed. I wonder what is the best practice of writing a Makefile for a Go project